# How to import specific column data from remote server to local PostgreSQL database?

Tags: database, postgresql

I hope this is a common problem. I have two different computers:

1. My development computer,
2. The running remote server computer

Each computer has its own running PostgreSQL database. Both computers have essentially the same table names with a few more tables in the development computer; but the table definitions and relationships have been changed in the development machine to better handle referential integrity and be 3NF compliant.

I need to import specific data (i.e., columns)  from the remote server into specific tables of the development computer (where the development tables have a different structure then the remote server).

How is this done in PostgreSQL? (I'm thinking simply loading the table from a pgdump would overrite the newer development table structure??).

Something along the lines of (pseudocode)

using PostgreSQL 9.3:

```
insert into <local computer> charges (tposted, patient_recid, fileoninsurance)
 select tposted, patient_recid, fileoninsurance 
 from <Remote Server> ( select e.tposted, e.patient_recid, d.fileoninsurance
    from encountertimes e
    join daysheets d on ( e.tposted = d.tposted and e.patient_recid =d.patient_recid).
```

Just to be clear, the table join needs to be done with the remote server tables, not the development machine.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use COPY to dump just the fields you want, and load them in the other db:

```
COPY (
  SELECT e.tposted, e.patient_recid, d.fileoninsurance
  FROM encountertimes e
  JOIN daysheets d USING(tposted, patient_recid)
) TO '/some/file'; -- or STDOUT

...

COPY charges (tposted, patient_recid, fileoninsurance) FROM '/some/file';
```

Alternatively, use [foreign data wrappers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/postgres-fdw.html), which would be fairly similar to your pseudosql.

You could also use `pg_dump` to dump just the data from your table, as INSERTs with named columns, so the table structures don't have to match exactly (as long as the target table is a superset of the exported one).